# Once I create and get a digital certificate signed, what next?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates

At the moment, I used [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php) to make what I believe is a signed certificate in php <- Please correct me if I'm incorrect with this. But either way, after making a signed certificate, what next? How do I use it for my website (an aws ec2 ubuntu instance)? Is my understanding all wrong? I'm guessing there are docs out their explaining this but I've been searching around for hours. If you guys have any questions on anything that wasn't clear, please state them.

Comment: This question is pretty broad and unfocused so I made it a duplicate of several other questions which explain key ideas.  *"Is my understanding all wrong?"* - you don't actually explain your understanding so it is impossible to tell. *"How do I use it for my website (an aws ec2 ubuntu instance)?"* - check the tutorial from AWS [Tutorial: Configure SSL/TLS on Amazon Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is all that I was looking for! I know this was somewhat a bad qusetion, but it saved me a few hours of research.